# how use Eclipse Web page Editor as Plugin Extension Point

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to add my custom component in the eclipse provided Web page Editor Palette. How to do that.Is there any way to use this as plug-in extension point as generally plugin development works.

I have already downloaded the source code of Visual Editor and but I am confused how to make it run because my eclipse already carrying VE based plug-ins. And if I remove those plug-ins then I am getting exception.
I removed all Jem and Ve plugins from eclipse plug-in folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explained the solution here -

[How to provide a custom component in the existing Web page Editor Palette](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5509679/how-to-provide-a-custom-component-in-the-existing-web-page-editor-palette)